# One to many and search in many (IQueryable) (linq)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, iqueryable

I have this kind of relationship in my database :

```
Order => historyStatus => Status
```

`Order` contains a list of `HistoryStatus` and `HistoryStatus` contains one `Status`.

My use case is: search all `Order` with a determined `Status` and get the latest `HistoryStatus` (based on date)

How can I do that in linq to entities and `IQueryable`?

Here are the entities :

```
public class Order 
{
   public int ID { get; set; }

   public virtual ICollection<HistoryStatusOrder> HistoriesStatusOrder { get; set; }
}

public class HistoryStatusOrder 
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string StatusOrderCode { get; 
    public int  OrderId { get; set; }

    public virtual StatusOrder StatusOrder { get; set; }
    public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
}

public class StatusOrder : IEntityBase<string>
{
    public string ID { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<HistoryStatusOrder> HistoriesStatusOrder { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my `Search` method:

```
// do multiple searches
if (searchOrderVM.OrderNumber != null)
    queryable = queryable.Where(x => x.OrderNumber.ToString().Contains(searchOrderVM.OrderNumber.ToString()));

// Next 
if (searchOrderVM.SelectedOrdersStatus != null)
{
    // Need to return queryable = ....
}

// Next search...
....

// Finally I do .ToList() to launch the query in database.
```

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Do you mean "Find the latest [HistoryStatus that has a particular Status value] for each Order" or "Find the HistoryStatus for each Order where the _latest_ HistoryStatus has a particular Status value"? Also, which property holds the date you mentioned?

Comment: I need to retrieve a IQueryable<Order> So I need to find all Orders with the latest HistoryStatusOrder based on Date and StatusOrderCode. I added the missing props.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would find all `Orders` where the latest `HistoryStatusOrder` for that `Order` had a particular `StatusOrderCode`:

```
var results = orders.Where (o => o.HistoriesStatusOrder
    .OrderByDescending (hso => hso.Date)
    .First().StatusOrderCode == "foobar");
```

(Assuming that each `Order` always had at least one `HistoryStatusOrder`)

You can write this query in a different way to preserve the `IQueryable<Order>`:

```
var results = orders
    .Select (o => new {
        Order = o,
        LatestHistoryStatusOrder = o.HistoriesStatusOrder
            .OrderByDescending (hso => hso.Date)
            .First()
    })
    .Where (x => x.LatestHistoryStatusOrder.StatusOrderCode == "foobar")
    .Select (x => x.Order);

foreach(var order in results)
{
    // Here you can access:
    //  order.ID
}
```

If you want to keep access to the `LatestHistoryStatusOrder`, you can skip the last `.Select(x => x.Order)` statement:

```
var results = orders
    .Select (o => new {
        Order = o,
        LatestHistoryStatusOrder = o.HistoriesStatusOrder
            .OrderByDescending (hso => hso.Date)
            .First()
    })
    .Where (x => x.LatestHistoryStatusOrder.StatusOrderCode == "foobar");

foreach(var item in results)
{
    // Here you can access:
    //   item.Order.ID
    //   item.LatestHistoryStatusOrder
}
```

Comment: Thx for your answer, but that is not what I want. I need  to return a IQueryable<Order> because I do multiple search. I will explain this in my first question :).

Comment: @Goba I've added an example that should preserve the `IQueryable<Order>`

Comment: Thank , It probably works but I use ORACLE 11g and I have this kind of error now :/  “oracle 11.2.0.3.0 does not support apply”

Comment: @Goba Hmm, this seems to be a [known problem for EntityFramework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896273.aspx), and probably one that will occur with many different queries against an Oracle database.

Comment: @Goba I suggest you look into newer versions of the Oracle Data Provider for .NET; maybe that would help, or upgrade to Oracle 12 which apparently supports `APPLY`. I'm afraid I have no experience with Oracle DBs, so I can't help you any further.

Comment: If I test with ToList() after orders. I retrieve Orders but multiple HistoryStatusOrder are inside each Order not just one.

Comment: Yes, doing `orders.ToList().Select(x => ..)` will retrieve _all_ the orders from the database, and then perform the query in-memory instead of performing the query against the database. This will get around the Oracle problem, but can lead to very slow performance later on when you have thousands of orders in your database.

Comment: There will always be multiple `HistoryStatusOrder` records inside each `Order` since the property represents the one-to-many relationship. If you want to keep the "latest" `HistoryStatusOrder` after it has been found, you can skip the `.Select(x => x.Order)` line at the end of the query, but then you'll have a query result that would not be `IQueryable<Order>`

Comment: Yep I know that ;) Unfortunately I cannot switch to Oracle 12. But when I test your code, I retrieve multiple HistoryStatusOrder not just one (the latest) for each Orders. Is not that I want. Are you understand ? :)  It not possible to filter the one to many ? Hum maybe add LatestHistory property inside the Entity History right ?

Comment: @Goba No, the `ICollection<HistoryStatusOrder>` property represents the entire set of related items in the database, you can select it, and filter it into another variable, but you can't really alter the composition of the _original_ property.